# The purpose of a double struck I in product notation equation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am currently undertaking a Discrete Mathematics course and I have been provided the below notation for which I can not identify the purpose of the $\mathbb I$ in the first equation.

$$I_k = \mathbb I\biggl(\prod_{k\in\mathcal J(n-1)} n \bmod k > 0\biggl)$$

$$\mathcal J(n) = \{2\le k \le n|I_k=1\}$$

Use within the set appears to indicate that the $\mathbb I$ is possibly indicating $I_k$ is a boolean result. I am not able to confirm this however as my current knowledge of Discrete Mathematics is not exactly high level.

Is anyone able to shed some light on what the purpose of the $\mathbb I$ is?

Comment: It is often used as an "indicator function".  The result is $1$ if the statement inside is true and $0$ if the statement is false.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks for the quick answer. You have confirmed what I thought was going on. If you put this as an answer, I'll happily mark it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is often used as an "indicator function". The result is $1$ if the statement inside is true and $0$ if the statement is false.